# Need to add footer bar in screen, using chrisbane pull to refresh

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I am beginner in Android and using Chrisbane PullToRefresh - https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

I have to add one bottom bar in screen, but as per the code it is using frame layout and adding layout at runtime.

I tried to add bottom bar, but it is adding on top of ListView, please help me to implement one bottom bar using PullToRefresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [this library](https://github.com/weixiao1984/Android-Infinite-Scroll-Listview). It has what you want already implemented. I used it, worked like a charm.

Or you can add a footer to your listview :

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: Hi Courblah, thanks for the option. I want pullToRefresh as well in list but this library has load more option it seems.

Comment: Hehe. As a matter of fact i used the same library with (https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) pull to refresh library. It works perfect.

Comment: I have also tried but it is moving the footer to the top, can you please provide me some sample project or code for this.

Comment: I got the point, i have changed that FrameLayout to Relative Layout and it worked :)